# How to schedule user-defined jobs with APscheduler in a Django view

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, apscheduler

The idea is to allow users to submit a time/date to the server to have a job scheduled to execute at the user-specified time.

My first choice was to do this in the view, where the data from the frontend is posted to. However, apscheduler returns a value error.

Below is a snippet from the view I wish to use for user-scheduled jobs and just a small test.

```
class SchedulePolicyDeployView(APIView):
 def post(self, request, version):

    def test_job():
        print("cron job test")

    scheduler.start()
    scheduler.add_job(test_job, "cron", id="test_job", day="*", minute="*/1")

    return Response("job scheduled successfully")
```

The error message returned is:

```
ValueError: This Job cannot be serialized since the reference to its callable (<function SchedulePolicyDeployView.post.<locals>.test_job at 0x05694C00>) could not be determined. Consider giving a textual reference (module:function name) instead.
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes I did. Tried to write my answer in here, but ran out of room. Will answer this and mark it as solved shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did fix this issue in my code; but it's changed quite a bit since I did asked this question. I've tried to bring it all in here though:

*assuming the scheduler object has already been initialised

scheduler.py

```
def schedule_job(arg1, arg2, arg3, time, job_id):
    scheduler.add_job(deploy_policy, 'date', args=[arg1, arg2, arg3], run_date=datetime(int(date['year']), int(date['month']), int(date['day']), int(time['hour']), int(time['minute']), 0))
    return Response({"message": "scheduled!"})
```

views.py

```
from scheduler import schedule_job
class SchedulePolicyDeployView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, version):
        schedule_job(apic, username, password, policy_url_and_payload_result, date_dict, time_dict, payload["job_id"])
        return Response({"result": "success"})
```